# How to resize already exising window and open new chrome window on the right side

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Currently i'm developing google chrome extension.
I tried using the below code

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
      chrome.windows.create({
        url,
        type: "panel",
        height:650,
        width: 400,
        focused: true,
        left:1000,
        top:100
      });
  });
```

I need to resize already existing window to half of the screen and open the new window on the other side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  chrome.windows.getCurrent((currentWindow) => {
    chrome.windows.update(currentWindow.id, {
      width: currentWindow.width / 2,
    });
    chrome.windows.create({
      url,
      type: "panel",
      height: 650,
      width: currentWindow.width / 2,
      focused: true,
      left: currentWindow.left + currentWindow.width / 2,
      top: 100,
    });
  });
});
```

This will first get the current window using chrome.windows.getCurrent and then update its width to half the screen width. After that, it will create a new window with the same height as the original window, but with half the width of the screen, starting from the right side of the original window.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to resize the existing window: (based on my reading of https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/)

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(window => window.width /= 2);
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. Any other solution?

Answer (score -1):

The key to making the above function work =
`chrome.windows.update(currentWindow.id, {width: currentWindow.width / 2});`

is that it won't work if the state is `maximized` or `fullscreen` so you also have to account for that and do:
`chrome.windows.update(currentWindow.id, {state: "normal", width: 900})`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).